# Excel VBA: FormulaArray error when integrated with modeFRONTIER

Tags: vba, excel, integration

I have a macro that works perfectly when I run it on Excel. It's basically something like:

```
 Range("A1:A3").formulaArray = "=myFunction(input1, input2, input3)"
```

When I try to integrate this macro with modeFRONTIER, I receive the error message "Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the range class". One "solution" I managed is to substitute the commas for semi-colons to separate the inputs on the VBA code, the problem then is that it works as intended on modeFRONTIER but doesn't when used in Excel!

Another detail is that I tried in another computer with the same modeFRONTIER release, project, VBA code and spreadsheet and not even the first "solution" worked.

I know it's a very specific question, but anyone had this problem (or similar) when trying to integrate excel with different softwares?

Comment: What are `input1, input2, input3`? ranges? or variable names?

Comment: So, if it works fine, as you say, on excel - what is Frontier? And should you look there for an answer.

Comment: A.S.H: `input1, input2, input3` are ranges, `myFunction` is a polynomial fitting function that returns me the coefficients of the interpolation polynomial, very similar to LINEST. Solar Mike: about looking at modeFrontier for an answer, the problem isn't inherent to the software, since the macro works fine there after changing "," to ";", but won't work on Excel. mF is just a integration software for multidisciplinary optimization.

Comment: Not clear how modeFRONTIER will be involved in executing macros. But even with Excel it should be `Worksheets("mySheet").Range("A1:A3").FormulaArray = "=myFunction(input1, input2, input3)"`. Note the explicit defining of the sheet on which the range shall be and the leading "=" in the formula string. Without defining the sheet, the `ActiveSheet` is meant and this could not be the desired. And without the leading "=" it does even not work in Excel, at least for me.

Comment: @AxelRichter you are right, I forgot to add the "=" sign when asking the question. I define my worksheet in another line so that should't be a problem, although thank you for the comment. 
modeFRONTIER has a native integration with Excel, I declare my variables and the calculations in Excel and use mF for the sampling, genetic algorithm and further multi-objective optimization (the result I am willing to optimize is obtained with said macro).